# Ruby on Rails, Enum user conditions from a different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, enums

I have enums declared as follows in a table separate from my main users table (User.rb). I sign up users and give them a role from this table:

school_user.rb

```
class SchoolUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :school

    enum user_type: [:school, :student, :parent, :teacher]

def school?
end

def teacher?
end

def student?
end

def parent?
end


end
```

I don't think I have to define each role here but I tried it.

I was using a boolean method to separate the users before but switched to enum. I used to use this method type to restrict views based on role:

```
...unless current_user.teacher?...
```

This worked fine but now I have the enums declared in a different model to the users table it does not work.

A user has a role through the relationship between user.rb and school_user.rb. This works. I'm just looking for a way to set access based on user role/type in the views as above.

I hope not but I presume I will have to change all the conditions throughout my application?

I tried:

```
...unless current_user.school_user.teacher?...
```

and other variations.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Edit: User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, presence:true,
            length: {minimum: 4 }
  validates :last_name, presence:true

  has_many :messages, foreign_key: :sender_id
  has_many :notes
  has_one :school_user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :school_user
```

Comment: Can you post your user model?

Comment: @Pavan - I edited the question - included user.rb

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". It's much better to provide minimal code examples that demonstrate the problem, than try to describe it which requires us to imagine your code. Without the detail your question is broad.

Comment: Also try removing those methods(`school?`, `teacher?` etc) in the `school_user` model

Comment: Tried this but get undefined method for teacher?, school? etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate this methods to `:school_user`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :school?, :student?, :parent?, :teacher?, to: :school_user
```

Also, remove this methods from `SchoolUser` class, as mentioned in comments